# Для чего нужны инкремент и декремент помимо создания циклов?

Tags: javascript

Для чего нужны инкремент и декремент помимо создания циклов?

Comment: как ни странно: для увеличения и уменьшения значения переменной

Answer (score 0):

У них нет определённого назначения. Даже в циклах их использовать необязательно. (Можно писать `i += 1` или `i = i + 1`.) Это просто инструмент языка, дополнительный функционал для удобства разработки. Хочешь - используй, не хочешь - не используй.